# jQuery Datepicker altField issue

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I am having some trouble with a jQuery datepicker widget. This code is working as expected and the alert(tempDate) returns a date in dd-mm-yyyy format:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        //showOtherMonths: true,
        //selectOtherMonths: true,
        altField: "#alternate",
        altFormat: "d-m-yy"
    });
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "DD d MM, yy");
    $("#datepicker").change(function(){
        var tempDate = $("#alternate").val();
        alert(tempDate);
    });
});
```

However, when I add in a minDate and maxDate, the alert(tempDate) returns nothing:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: -20, maxDate: +20 });
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        //showOtherMonths: true,
        //selectOtherMonths: true,
        altField: "#alternate",
        altFormat: "d-m-yy"
    });
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "DD d MM, yy");
    $("#datepicker").change(function(){
        var tempDate = $("#alternate").val();
        alert(tempDate);
    });
});
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<label>Date: </label><input type="text" id="datepicker" size="30"><input type="hidden" id="alternate"  />
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are setting the options twice and so you are overriding the options, try setting them all once.

Code:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    minDate: -20,
    maxDate: +20,
    altField: "#alternate",
    altFormat: "d-m-yy",
    dateFormat: "DD d MM, yy"
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/6Vk9E/2/

Comment: Faster than me. I'd add that `dateFormat` can be set with everything else. No need to set it separately. And I'd chain everything instead of selecting `#datepicker` again.

Comment: @toxalot true, I have added it to the answer